# Android animation translate and scale at the same time is not what I want

Tags: android, animation

I want write an animation that translate a view and scale it at the same time. It's a simple animation, but when run, it doesn't work right. It runs as a curve but not a straight line.
The view's layout xml and the anim.xml is below

```
//activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Main2Activity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="clickBtn"
    android:text="startAnim"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

 // anim.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:duration="8000"
 android:shareInterpolator="true">

 <translate
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="-100%p" />

<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="1"
    android:toAlpha="0" />

<scale
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="0.2"
    android:toYScale="0.2" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For running two animations at the same time, you can use `AnimatorSet`.

> In many cases, you want to play an animation that depends on when another animation starts or finishes. The Android system lets you bundle animations together into an `AnimatorSet`, so that you can specify whether to start animations simultaneously, sequentially, or after a specified delay. You can also nest `AnimatorSet` objects within each other.

Make two separate animations(one for translate and one for scale) and start them using `AnimatorSet`.

For more information you can visit here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation

Comment: Yeah, AnimatorSet is property animator, but I think view animation can do that. Can't it?